# How to break when contents of a div is changing?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

Here is my code:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\jquery2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myDiv').html('Hello World');
        });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="myDiv">
          Some text...
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The scenario is, I have no idea what is changing the div content. How do I use chrome, firefox or firebug (pick one) to work out what is changing 'myDiv'?**

*Ideally I want to be able to add a break point on the div just before it changes, so at this point 'Some text...' will be displayed on screen. I step through the code and see the JavaScript code that interacts with the div. Then after stepping through, I see the div content change from 'Some text...' to 'Hello World'. Is this all bonkers? Please explain why if so.*

Comment: Open the console, navigate to the line of script you want to break on, and click on the breakpoint by clicking the left hand margin of the line. Refresh the page and execution will then stop at that point.

Comment: you shouldnt do this src="C:\jquery2.js".

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - Using which application?

Comment: Any DOM inspector. They all work in roughly the same way.

Comment: @Annop Joshia - Yes I know, I am learning jquery, this is just dummy code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Doesn't seem to work on chrome or firefox, am I missing something?

Comment: Do you literally mean "when the DIV content changes" or just at the line of code where you change the DIV contents yourself?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I want it to break at the point when the div is changing please.

Comment: Answer update to match edited requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you actually want to break on DOM changes, and not code, you can do that as follows:

**Google Chrome DevTools:**

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to call up the DOM inspector.
2. Right-click on the element (inside of the DOM inspector) that you want to break on.
3. In the upcoming context menu choose *Break on...* > *Subtree modifications*

Screenshot from this page:

[image: Enabling breaking on subtree modifications in Chrome DevTools]

**Firebug:**

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Firebug.
2. Right-click on the element (inside the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel)) that you want to break on.
3. In the upcoming context menu choose *Break On Child Addition or Removal*

[image: Enabling breaking on subtree modifications in Firebug]

### Update

You now wish to insert the data breakpoint prior to your jQuery loading, so effectively on page load. You can do this by break pointing a line of javascript, *that is not in a DOM load event*, so that it breaks immediately. You can then insert the DOM-change breakpoint (in Chrome using the information above) and continue running. It should then break on the DOM change.

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\jquery2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Breakpoint on this line as it runs immediately during page load");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myDiv').html('Hello World');  // This does not run until the DOM finishes loading
        });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="myDiv">
          Some text...
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In theory you could breakpoint on the `$(document).ready(function()` line, but debuggers can do weird things on lines with inline callback

Comment: When I do this, nothing seems to happen. I am adding breakpoints on '<div id="myDiv">Hello World</div>' (Subtree & Attribute modified). Ideally what I want to see is, when I load the page, the code to break before the div content has changed, so I should see 'Some text..'. Then after I step over, then I see the div content change. But I want to do this without adding a breakpoint on the javascript that changes it. The scenario is I have no idea what javascript is changing it. (Will edit question).

Comment: Adding a data-only break point, *before you load the page*, isn't possible. You can only add code breakpoints, but that might be enough if you place one early on to stop the code... will update.